# Manually connecting mySQL to eclipse/Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I wanted to ask if I need to specify a path to my SQL file when using eclipse and spring Boot? I am given the same error `Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE`. All the settings are right, I believe, but the problem is that I never told eclipse where my databases are?

I do have a properties file that states this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Is this a way for it to find the db_example, and should it somehow be online when I start my project? When i go to localhost:3306 it also shows an error. I haven't been able to solve this problem in 2 days, and am pretty new to programming so please bear with me!

Dependecies (including HikariCP)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.msela</groupId>
    <artifactId>course-api-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>course-api-data</name>
    <description>Course API with Spring Data</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**EDIT 1**

I get this warning also:

```
2017-07-28 11:05:35.957  WARN 9576 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

**EDIT 2**
Screenshot of my path
[image]

**EDIT 3**

The error message after moving the folder is the following:

```
2017-07-28 11:40:20.348  WARN 10944 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: As stated in your other question(s) you need to include a `DataSource` implementation. You haven't provided one... Add something like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) as a dependency.

Comment: have you added the mySQL connector dependency in Maven/Gradle ?

Comment: I added HiakriCP and I added mySQL, the problem still persists!

Comment: It seem like your springboot app keeps using Derby Db (which is embedded) . Now that you removed it, you should update your maven in eclipse : Right click your App => maven => update.

Comment: Hmm, I did update it, and ran Maven... Still shows the same error

Comment: are you sure your application.properties file is under resource folder ? Can you post a screenshot of your app structure tree ?

Comment: There it is, just posted the picture.

Comment: copy and paste your application properties file in your src_main_resource folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see your `application.properties` in the resource folder. Your `application.properties` is in the test environment instead. i wont work like that.

Comment: Oh god, so that was the problem! But now it shows a bunch of errors instead of the one from before, saying it cannot load driver :/

Comment: but I assume you corrected : spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver right as pointed by another user ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's now spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Do I need to do something with maven or the properties file, or should maven-install and upgrade Maven suffice?

Comment: Short answer but efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

Please change `spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to this `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.
Your final database config may like this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Also please update your pom.xml file `dependencies` to this and run a `maven update` in eclipse:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you please update dependencies and run a maven update with above config

Comment: Did this, still same error.. Is there something I should add to my App? I currently have this:
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"io.msela"})
@EntityScan("io.msela.springbootstarter")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = EmployeeRepository.class)

Comment: Are you still getting this error `Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE` after updating with the above configuration

Comment: It seem like your springboot app keeps using Derby Db (which is embedded) . Now that you removed it, you should update your maven in eclipse : Right click your App => maven => update.

Comment: @Asker did you run maven update after updating pom.xml

Comment: I installed maven, updated project, and ran my application, this still doesn't work :/ same error.